# Ruby trying to dynamically create unicode string throws "invalid Unicode escape" error

Tags: ruby, string, dynamic, unicode

I have a requirement wherein I want to dynamically create a unicode string using interpolation.For e.g. please see the following code tried out in irb

```
2.1.2 :016 > hex = 0x0905
 => 2309 
2.1.2 :017 > b = "\u#{hex}"
SyntaxError: (irb):17: invalid Unicode escape
b = "\u#{hex}"
```

The hex-code 0x0905 corresponds to unicode for independent vowel for DEVANAGARI LETTER A.

I am unable to figure how to achieve the desired result.

Comment: It seems you don't know how to format code block, which is a little surprising to see on a long-time user, please read [the help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and don't add your signature any more.

Comment: Thanks Yu Hao.Will take care of your points in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass an encoding to [`Integer#chr`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Integer.html#method-i-chr):

```
hex = 0x0905
hex.chr('UTF-8') #=> "अ"
```

The parameter can be omitted, if [`Encoding::default_internal`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Encoding.html#method-c-default_internal) is set to UTF-8:

```
$ ruby -E UTF-8:UTF-8 -e "p 0x0905.chr"
"अ"
```

You can also append codepoints to other strings:

```
'' << hex #=> "अ"
```

Comment: This answer seems more compact compared to Uri Agassi's answer. However both the techniques work smoothly. Thank you Uri and Stefan to both of you.

Answer (score 1):

String interpolation happens *after* ruby decodes the escapes, so what you are trying to do is interpreted by ruby like an incomplete escape.

To create a unicode character from a number, you need to [`pack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-pack) it:

```
hex = 0x0905
[hex].pack("U")
=> "अ"
```